What object should I store many strings in?
I have a process where I must (de)tokenize payment account information. Currently, when sending a file to client with payment information (among other things), the actual payment account numbers are tokenized and it needs to be detokenized before sending it to the client.
The existing process loads a file into memory, loops through it line by line, detokenizes payment account fields (if it finds it) then adds it to internal StringBuilder variable. At the end, when the file was processed, this variable is converted into a byte array, loaded into memory stream and sent via SFTP to the client. Basically at no point do we store a file with clear text (untokenized accounts) on the server. Clear text payment accounts only exist in memory and then sent out to the client.
The problem comes on occasion, when the files are too large, the StringBuilder runs out of memory and we are unable to process the file.
Question: is there a better way to load and process large volumes of strings in memory using a different object? Maybe List?
I was thinking of using byte array right off the bat, since we use that to load into memory stream anyway, but it needs to be a defined size and I'm not sure how to get it (the function that detokenizes it does not directly accesses the source file, it uses a custom object with that information populated already).
Thank you

when the files are too large, How large is too large?

Are you running as a 32-bit process, or a 64-bit process? Don't guess.

32bit, can't switch to 64. The current file that's failing is around 100Mb. I wouldn't have guessed it would cause OOM exceptions, but it does. During debugging the RAM footprint of the app balloons to 1.2Gb. One of the temp solution that seems to work (so far) is applying editbin.exe /largeaddressaware to the executable. But that is a manual process that we would like to avoid.

Why can't you switch to 64-bit?

Too many dependencies.

So you specifically tried running as 64-bit and it didn't work?

Have you tried using MemoryStream instead, and take StringBuilder out of the picture? https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/132li23/using_memorystream_with_streamwriter/
